# How to draw a virtual framebuffer in Swing?

Tags: java, image, swing

Suppose I have an array `fb` that is large enough to hold each 32-bit color pixel for a 128x128 display. It's laid out like a framebuffer would be.

How can I efficiently draw this on the display?

My current method loops over every pixel but that seems rather slow and cumbersome. Is there no way to convert this to an Image?

EDIT: I want to do this using the Java Swing APIs. I do not want any platform-specific code. However, if there is a library that uses the Swing APIs, that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current method loops over every pixel but that seems rather slow and cumbersome. Is there no way to convert this to an Image?

You can paint it onto a `BufferedImage`.

Then you can use the `BufferedImage` to create an `ImageIcon` and use the Icon to create a `JLabel` and add the label to your GUI.

Edit:

> I want to convert the int array to a BufferedImage

How about the `setRGB(...)` method of the `BufferedImage`?

Comment: I know how to get it in my GUI. I want to convert the `int` array to a BufferedImage without manually painting.

Comment: I think that may work. Please add that info to your answer.

Comment: @MarkYisri glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

[Cairo](https://www.cairographics.org/cairo-java/) is a library thats suports 2D graphics rendering and can be used from Java.

[SDLJava](http://sdljava.sourceforge.net/) is a Java port of the popular C SDL game development library. This also should be able to do what you ask for, although it doesn't seem to have been updated since 2005 so if you have any problems with it support may not be forthcoming.

As an alternative, you could always use some fairly simple C code to open and configure the framebuffer, and then use JNI to return the memory-mapped framebuffer as a direct-mode ByteBuffer, so you can draw to it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please note that I wanted to do this by using the Swing APIs directly, not any platform-dependent code. Please see my edit. Also, why did you copy the answer from another question?